# Invalid conversion error while using malloc

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, malloc

I am trying to write a shell program in C. The following function is supposed to get user line input. I keep receiving an "invalid conversion from `void*` to `char**` error on the line where I attempt to malloc.

I do not understand why. Can anyone explain?

```
char *get_line_input(void)
{
  int scan;
  int buff_size = 1024;
  int argument_tracker = 0;
  char *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * buff_size);

  while (1) {
    scan = getchar();
    if (scan == '\n') {
      line[argument_tracker] = '\0';
      return line;
    } else {
      line[argument_tracker] = scan;
    }
    argument_tracker++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a c++ compiler

Comment: Cannot reproduce: clean compilation.

Comment: from '`void*`' to '`char**`'  typo as from '`void*`' to '`char*`' ?

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#error arrrgh! C++` `#endif`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a C++ compiler/C++ mode where there's no implicit conversion from `void*` to `T*`. In C, you shouldn't get this error as `void*` can be assigned to any other data pointer without explicit cast.

Either you can use a C compiler or if you must use C++ compiler then cast appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Because `void *` can't be implicitly converted to `char *` in c++ and you're probably using c++. Quick fix:

```
char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * buff_size);
```

You should read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)